# How to create a different Maven project with major relase version?

Tags: java, maven, svn

We have current release 1.0.0 maven project and in parallel we want to work on the 2.0.0 maven project which we would like to rewrite the code from the scratch. Should we create the release 2.0.0 as new maven project, if we create as new project it fails in eclipse as the artifacts name conflicts. Can you recommend how we should create 2.0.0 release and update to the SVN?

Below is how we defined the current project

```
<project >  
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.test.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-rest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo-rest</name>
    <repositories>
    ....
    </repositories>
    <properties>
       ...
    </properties>    
     <dependencies>
     ....
     </dependencies> 

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard approach is to have separate branches when you introduce new version and also support old version.

As you are going to do complete rewrite, you don't have problems about merging code into new version branch.

But you are right, you can't work on two projects with same artifact name in same Eclipse workspace. 
You have two options:

- Developers will be switching workspace between projects (which make sense if you don't want them to copy code snippets from old project)
- You will rename new version of the project (which also does make sense if it is complete rewrite)

**Responding to question in comment:**

If you need to maintain old version alongside new version, than you need to create discipline across the team to merge each fix/enhancement from 1.0.0 branch into 2.0.0 branch (if appropriate). With this approach you would have all the fixes and enhancements in the latest version. There are tools that can help with tracking merged fixes (e.g. [TortoiseSVN merge feature](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html)). You can maintain even more branches this way. But the rule is that each change from older branches needs to be merged into all newer branches.
Of course name of the artifact stays and developers will need to switch workspaces or rebase branches.

Comment: What if i don't rewrite the code and just want to release 2.0.0 with same artifact name?